# Building custom cocoapods failing (swift and obc class)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I made a cocoapod that uses both swift and obj c so Im using a bridging header to connect them.

When `Build Libraries for Distribution = NO`
The cocoapod will still compile but running the `xcodebuild` command will give an error `No 'swiftinterface' files found within`

When `Build Libraries for Distribution = YES`
The cocoapod wont compile with an error of `error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported: Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code`

When `Build Libraries for Distribution = YES` and I remove the bridging header,
The cocoapod wont compile since swift and objc files wont be visible with each other.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build it with `Build Libraries for Distribution = NO`. The problem was the naming of my class. I have a class named LocationManager so I renamed it with something different then it worked.